# How to increase the size of Percent Values in pie chart of MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using MPAndroidChart for displaying a PieChart like in the image and
I want to increase the size of percentage values, like 38%, 14% and so on but I can't find any methods to do so.
[image]

Comment: Does `mChart.setEntryLabelTextSize()` only sets size of name?

Comment: Yes, they only affect the size of labels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work :

```
// reference to your data
PieData data = new PieData(labels, dataSet);

// this increases the values text size  
data.setValueTextSize(40f); // <- here
```